# Flutter can't move cursor in textformfield

Tags: flutter, input, position, text-cursor

As my title says i can't move cursor anywhere inside `TextFormField` anyone faced the same issue as me ? could

please help.

i looked everywhere and haven't seen anyone has same issue as me i even tried adding `textDirection` from Left To Right but it doesn't solve my issue

```
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
```

and thanks .

Comment: Which platform, and what's your Flutter version?

Comment: android and Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable

Answer (score -1):

You should add a listener to textfield. For example;

```dart
    _controller.addListener(() {
      _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
        text: _controller.text,
        selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 2), // Here your position calculate logic
        composing: TextRange.empty,
      );
    });
```